# AttributeError :- 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith' In Django views:-

Tags: python, django-views

AttributeError :- 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith' In Django views:-

```
def index(request):
    value = []
    path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'accessfiles/media/images/GSE2035_series_matrix.txt')
    with open(path, 'r', encoding = "utf-8") as file:
        file = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
        for line in file:
            if line.startswith("!Series_relation"):
                value = line[1]


        args = {'file':value}
        return render(request, 'index.html', args)
```

Comment: `csv.reader()` returns a list of columns. Also do not assign two different objects to var named 'file'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The startswith() method is defined for string objects. In this case you call it on the line variable, which is a list object (as the error suggests).

When reading a csv file it will split up each line into a list of values, in this case the values that are delimited by the tab character in the original file.

If you want to make sure that the line starts with for example "start" you should write:

```
line[0].startswith("start")
```

because the first element of the line list will be a string.

Answer (score 0):

`csv.reader` returns an iterator which contains lists, each list represents a line in the file split by the provided delimiter (as can be inferred from the error you are receiving).
Try adding `print(line)` before the `if` statement.

For your code to work you will need to modify `if line.startswith(...)` to `if line[0].startswith(...)`.